# Why is Chandi Homa performed?

Tags: yajna, homam

Can any one tell the significance, importance of **Chandi Homa**  ?

Answer (score 7):

I'm adding a [PDF](http://www.vedicastrologer.org/homam/chandi/chandi_homam_english.pdf) that teaches you the  details of how to perform a Chandi Homam.This document also tells you about its importance which i have quoted below.

I'm sure that you are just curious to know.If your intent is doing  the homam on your own by following this document then that is **strongly not recommended**.Although this Acharya is genuinely learned in Scriptures.But still do not attempt.Even the document itself is having a word of caution.

> Chandi is a very fierce and powerful deity – She is  the primordial
>   energy that is responsible for  the creation, sustenance and
>   destruction of this en tire universe. She is the sum total of the 
>   energies of all beings of this universe. **Chandi homam is
>   unquestionably a very powerful  sadhana.  This ritual  can  be used
>   for getting wealth and health, for success  in various wordly matters
>   and  for destroying enemies.** However, one performing Cha ndi homam for
>   such a specific purpose  needs to meet some exacting demands, such as
>   perfec t pronunciation, perfect procedure and  perfect materials for
>   the purpose, and have some accumulated spiritual energy to pull off
>   the  feat .  Neither is the author an expert in performing homam  with
>   such an attitude nor does he teach that.  This document is strictly
>   for one who performs Chandi homam for spiritual upliftment and looks 
>   at the Divine Mother as a mother and looks at onese lf as a helpless
>   child who desperately wants  to improve. This document is strictly for
>   one who i s willing to undergo whatever one’s mother  wants one to
>   undergo, for the sake of spiritual upl iftment.  However, it is  not 
>   necessary that She should take away one’s material  success and
>   prosperity in  order to give spiritual upliftment. In fact, many p
>   eople who perform Chandi homam everyday or  every week using this
>   document may experience continued or even increased material success 
>   (and yet be able to remain detached from it and pro gress
>   spiritually). However, in  some  cases,  She  may  decide to give a
>   shock or two in worldly matters if  something is badly blocking one’s 
>   spiritual progress and a setback is needed. The pat h towards
>   self-realization is different for each  person. She knows the best for
>   each person. Unless  one is willing to surrender to Her completely 
>   and accept whatever comes one’s way – good or bad –  as Her blessings
>   **and unless one does not  expect  any specific material benefit from
>   this homam, one  should  not  use this document to perform Chandi
>   homam.**

**Off Topic**-[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ANy3mVf2h00) you can see the same Acharya(who composed the PDF) performing a Mahaganapati Homam.

Comment: @rickross-For any homams the mantra pronounciation should be clear.PDF and all are recent. You should know about Aapasthamba and anugnais for these homams.

Comment: @ParthasarathyRaghavan It is not necessary for everyone to know about apastambha sutras .They are only followed in South India by those who follow Krishna Yajurveda ,Taitteriya shaka.They r said to be of Andhra Brahmin origin.And this acharya who composed this pDf and who is doing the Homam in the video given in the answer is an andhra brahmin only.So he knows his stuffs

Comment: @Rickross--The culture varies across India. Apasthamba is the beginning of homam and Anugnai is the grace we seek from the Lord for the homam to be done in a good way.

Comment: Apasthambha is the beginning for u mite be not for all.

Comment: That is why I told culture varies-- we follow as per sastras.and reference thru various books.

Comment: Yes that is what i have said too..U said for doing a homa one SHOULD know Apasthambha.I said NO its not necessary.Not every shaka follows the same sutras.There are many,many other Kalpa texts.The apasthambha is just  one among those many.

Comment: But we adhere as per sastras.Here ends the argument.

Comment: And whos here not adhering as per scriptures??The Acharya is more learned than u.He himself is a Guru & he has learned the Shastras from his Guru.in ur case u dont have a guru .U learn from prayoga books easily avialable in markets.That is all because this is Kali.And it is u who started an useless argument without chking the pdf not me..

Comment: @Rickross--My Guru is  acharya of Ahobila mutt and sadguru sainath. It is not market books. All are eminent scholars who wrote th ebook not like the one who copies like you the answers for questions from various smiritis and puranas. Experience yourself and answer.

Comment: @ParthasarathyRaghavan U only previously told that u dont have a guru urself ,that its difficult to find Gurus in Kali etc ,otherwise how will i know?Sadguru Sainath means Sai Baba??? ,i was talking about a living Guru.Do u have one ?I guess NO.

Comment: And those who composed Smritis,Puranas are not eminent persons ?/haha They are called Maharishis.

Comment: I mentioned Ahobila mutt jeer is my guru. Can't you understand English. Puranas smritis composed by eminent persons for you people to copy and provide the answers easily. They are scholars learned men.

Comment: You are jealous of me performing Homa. So you are brimming.

Comment: Then u must have lied previously ,how can i know ur personal details without u telling me..And yes i do understand english but then u also told that sai baba is ur guru..i was not talking about that...talkng abt the guru sisya lineage..who is ur immediate Guru in that case?

Comment: haha  i have learnt from my Guru himself..jealous of u???...haha..u still learning from prayoga books and thats y asking a lots of questions to get clarification.

Comment: Ahobila mutt jeer   how many times I have to mention?

Comment: I am not asl=king about homam u know-- refer my questions. You are not reading the questions properly it seems.

Answer (score 2):

The significance of Chandi Homa is that it can support you in removing complications and hurdles on your track to victory. Goddess Durga, the chief divinity of this Homa will gift you with the control to stable your desire and calmness, tolerance and rejection. With her blessing, you will be able to manifest your true divine Self that bonds self-centeredness and self-sacrifice.

Chandi Homa is important because it is one of the most authoritative homa for an individual to achieve accomplishments in their lifespan and also it overcomes of all kinds of sins and blockades in one's whole life. This homa helps one to triumph over Adversaries. By performing the Maha Chandi Homa, one can become free from malicious eyes, difficulties, blockades and they are also bestowed with getting decent well-being, wealth, chastity and success.

Comment: Welcome To Hinduism SE! We have to provide  sources from authentic scriptures like "Mahabharata ", Ramayana" , "Devi Bhagvat" while giving answers on this site.Pls.add some sources in your answer.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar Unfortunately I do not know of any authentic sources that reference my answer. I answered from what I have learnt in swadhayay and did little research to back my answer. If you wish, I can take my answer down because of reliability issues.

Comment: Then mention this thing about sources in answer.Also  you can try to find some authentic web sites ,which are mentioning about your answer and  add at least one of them as a source in it.

Answer (score 2):

Goddess Chandi is known for her fierce form and plays a key role in protecting devotees from potential threats and risks. Doing Chandi homam once in a year eradicate all  hurdles and negative forces in your path and also clear all the obstacles in the path to success. [For more](http://www.vedicfolks.com/health/karma-remedies/homams/chandi-homam.html)

Comment: This is just a copy-paste from mentioned link. Visit [how ro reference](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). Note that blogs are not acceptable source. You should cite some authentic source preferably scriptures.